# Replace persian or arabic sentence to randomly generated english

Tags: php, random, replace, arabic, persian

How to replace persian or arabic sentence to randomly generated english words or sentence.
For example, I have an url as below

```
www.example.com/arti/19029/متی-نتها-نیبتی/new
```

I want to convert it as below

```
www.example.com/arti/19029/xideo-oiend/new
```

xideo-oiend is just a randomly generated words and its nothing to do with متی-نتها-نیبتی .

Only replacing persian or arabic sentence to english randomly generated sentence. How to find that its a arabic sentence in php.

Comment: Does it need to always generate the same string?

Comment: @Dave no ...it should different for every url

Comment: I mean like a hashing function, where `متی-نتها-نیبتی` -> `xideo-oiend` always, and another string would return something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like an "arabian tag" or something on strings which you could evaluate. Instead you'd have to define a detection routine yourself, though that should not be too difficult:

In php you get the requested url (`/arti/19029/متی-نتها-نیبتی/new` in your example) inside the superglobal $_SERVER var. You can disect it using a regular expression (take a look at the `preg_match()` function) and extract those portions of the string that match certain characteristics. In your case you'd have to look for a certain range of characters inside the string, namely arabian characters.

Things get much easier if that arabian part of the string always occurs at the same position inside the requested url. Then you don't have to check for certain characters but can use a simpler pattern search instead.

Comment: the problem is arabic string are not occuring at the same position for all urls which i am working on it...is there any way to find arabic words in a url ?

Comment: I answered that above. In that case you have to look for character sequences in the request string. Take a look at how arabic characters are encoded (which numbers represent those characters), best is to find the range that covers the whole arabic alphabet. Then you can write a regular expression looking for any substring composed of characters inside that range. Either look for character tables in the internet or type the alphabeth in a text file and examine that using a hexeditor afterwards. Such an editor shows you the exact way how each character is encoded inside a file.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you _share_ your solution. It might be of interest for others stumbling over your question later. And this site is about helping and sharing...

Answer (score 0):

Of course... But its a bit slow and I am looking for alternative solution.
First I used explode function :

```
$pieces  = explode('/',$url);
```

Then I used `implode()` function with `array_slice()` to get first part of URL (URL until Arabic words):

```
$part1 = implode('/', array_slice($pieces, 0, 3));
```

Then again I used `implode()` function with `array_slice()` to get last part of URL

```
$part2 = implode('/', array_slice($pieces, 4, 5));
```

At last I joined them with random generating string function in middle:

```
    $url = $part1.'/'.RandomString().'/'.$part2
```

It maybe silly solution but it worked. If you have better solution then please post it.